# Not understanding return in this recursive function (C++)

Tags: c++, recursion

```
    string stringtest(const string& s, int size, int index, string res){

       if(index == size){return res;}

        char c = s.at(index);

        if(isalpha(c)){ res+= c ; }

      **return**  stringtest(s,size,index+1,res);

    }

    string stringtest(const string& s){
        int size = s.size();
        string r = "";

     return stringtest(s,size,0,r);

    }

    int main(){
      cout <<   stringtest("1a2bc3def") << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Hello. This is a piece of code I wrote to learn recursion.

What i do not understand is the functioning of the return inside the helper function stringtest(string,size,index,result) - I just want to return the result at the end, why do I return the function call each time?

*EDIT*

So.. is it because when I return res it returns back to the calling function and since I never return those function calls then it never gets back to where I call stringtest("1a2...") in the main?

Comment: The function has a string return type.  If you don't have have that return statement it won't compile.

Think of the return statement as two statements instead..  One declares a local string that takes the result of calling the function recursively.  The second one actually returns it

Comment: Use a debugger and step into the code. In a few minutes, you should understand it properly. Even better, write what you get at each step on paper.

Comment: It is always allowed and relatively easy to add a pair of removable cout's to display a 'graphic' illustrating recurse / decurse action.  See example at:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58324382/2785528.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing to understand is that `return` followed by some expression does not immediately return some value. It computes the expression (which represents the recursive call) and then returns the value that the computed expression evaluates to. You are missing the intermediate computation that is done before some value is returned.

Within this intermediate computation, because of the recursion, it will launch another intermediate computations whose result it will return *once computed*. These intermediate computations keep being launched until the base case of the recursion is reached.

Without the `return` statement at the end, because the function has a non-void return type, you encounter undefined behavior.

Comment: @Valerie With a void return type, you would be unable to use the value outside of the function because is never returned outside. Right now you return the value and print it from the outside. With a void return type, you would need to print from the inside, replacing `return stringtest(s,size,index+1,res)` with `cout << stringtest(s,size,index+1,res) << endl`. Note that the printing order will be reverse, you will see output starting from the last index because of the recursive nature, and the logic is similar to the way I described it for the `return` statement situation.

Answer (score 0):

> What i do not understand is the functioning of the return inside the
>   helper function stringtest(string,size,index,result) - I just want to
>   return the result at the end, why do I return the function call each
>   time?

It is always allowed (and relatively easy) to add a pair of removable cout's to display a 'graphic' illustrating the recurse / decurse action.  Each function call (of stringtest()) returns to the line after the call.

I added a single parameter to track the recursion level, "size_t rLvl".  Note that in the decursion the rLvl is restored.  The rLvl is used to displace the current value,  thus increasing rLvl during recurse pushes the intermediate values of 'res' to the right, and the restore of rLvl during decurse restores the alignment of the decurse report with corresponding recurse report.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout, std::endl; // c++17

#include <iomanip>
using std::setw;

#include <string>
using std::string, std::to_string;


string stringtest(size_t rLvl, // recurse lvl
                  const string& s, size_t size, size_t index, string res)
{
   int w = static_cast<int>(2*rLvl);
   if(index == size)  // recursion termination clause
   {
      int sz = static_cast<int>(s.size());
      cout << "\n  " << setw(3) << rLvl
           << "  " << s << setw(w-sz-4) << " "
           << res << "   <<<<< end-of-recursion";
      return res;
   }

   char c = s.at(index);

   if(isalpha(c)) { res += c; }  // append c when it is alpha

   // vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv

   cout << "\n  " << setw(3) << rLvl                 // recurse report
        << setw(w) << " "
        << setw(4) << res << " ";

   string temp = stringtest(rLvl+1, // recurse lvl   // recursion invocation
                            s, size, index+1, res);

   cout << "\n  " << setw(3) << rLvl                 // decurse report
        << setw(w) << " "
        << setw(4) //<< "-"
        << res << '_';  //<< ")";

    // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

   return temp;
}

string stringtest(const string& s)
{
   size_t size = s.size();
   string r = "";
   return stringtest(1, s, size, 0, r);
}

int main()
{
   string res = stringtest("1a2bc3def");
   cout << "\n\n  result: " <<  res  << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
    1       
    2       a 
    3         a 
    4          ab 
    5           abc 
    6             abc 
    7              abcd 
    8                abcde 
    9                  abcdef 
   10  1a2bc3def       abcdef   <<<<< end-of-recursion
    9                  abcdef_
    8                abcde_
    7              abcd_
    6             abc_
    5           abc_
    4          ab_
    3         a_
    2       a_
    1      _

  result: abcdef
```