# converting a common recursion to tail recurtion because of stack overflow for large inputs

Tags: c++, recursion, tail-recursion

I have found this algorithm for a program that returns number of possible triangles with a specific perimeter. I know that this problem has some other ways but using them I get time limit error for large numbers maybe because they are not optimized. This one seems much more optimized but I get stack overflow for recursion for large inputs. Can anyone help me optimize it by converting it into tail recursion or do something else with this problem?

Here is my found algorithm:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int foo(int);
int main(){
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    cout<<foo(n);
    return 0;
}
int foo(int n){
    int p=n/2-2;
    int t;
    if(p%6<5&&p%6>0)
        t=(p+6-p%6)/6;
    else if(p%6==5)
        t=(p+6-p%6)/6+1;
    else
        t=p/6;
    if(n==3||n==5||n==6)
        return 1;
    else if(n==4)
        return 0;
    else{
        if(n%2==0)
            return foo(n-3);
        else
            return foo(n+1)+t;
    }
}
```

Comment: Kudos, your code compiles.  Now, please provide some test inputs with expected results to achieve an [MCVE].  I know it looks reasonably minimal at the moment, but review "https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example" ... we need to know what inputs reproduce the errors you are experiencing.

Comment: How are you convincing yourself the code is or is not tail-recursive?

Comment: What compilation options are you specifying ... I think I have never seen -O0 output  tail recursive executable.

Comment: Consider reviewing  https://stackoverflow.com/a/58324382/2785528 for an idea on how to understand order-of-execution for recursive function.

Comment: I voted to close as off-topic because your problem does not fall within the scope defined in the help center.  The problem is not reproducible without inputs and expected outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
return foo(n+1) + t;
//              ^^^
```

The addition makes the recursive call to `foo` not being the very last thing that happens in the function. So you need to move that addition *into* the function:

```
return foo(n + 1, t);
```

To make the other recursive call compatible, you'll just provide addition's neutral element:

```
return foo(n-3, 0);
```

New function's signature:

```
int foo(int n, int offset = 0); // default parameter allows for calling just as before.
```

Final question remaining: Where to do the addition???

Well, two places are obvious:

```
if(n==3||n==5||n==6)
    return 1 + offset;
else if(n==4)
    return /*0 +*/ offset;
```

`offset` is the accumulated offset of all previous recursive calls! So you will have to add it to whatever you add to next function's recursive call, so:

```
// ...
else if(n % 2 == 0)
    return foo(n-3, /*0 +*/ offset);
else
    return foo(n+1, t + offset);
```

Side note: Your algorithm doesn't seem to be suitable for negative numbers. Calling (unmodified) `foo` with these ends up in recurring until stack overflow (if stack was large enough, would possibly result in undefined behaviour due to signed integer overflow). If you don't intend to use it on negative numbers you *absolutely* should use `unsigned int` as data type! Otherwise, it needs appropriate fixing.

The values 0, 1 and 2 need special treatment, too, they lead to negative `n` (for unmodified `foo`, see above). But you could do that almost trivially:

```
if(n == 4)
{ ... }
else if (n < 6)
{ ... }
```

That would return 1 for n being 0, 1 or 2 (even with tail call optimised version, as offset would be still 0) and even spare some comparisons. If you need to return 0 for the special values: Simple, too:

```
else if (n < 6)
    return (n >= 3) + offset;
```

You could even merge all into one single condition:

```
if(n < 6)
    return (n == 3 || n > 4) + offset; // returning 0 for 0, 1, 2
    return (n <= 3 || n > 4) + offset; // returning 1 for 0, 1, 2
```

Greatest advantage: during all those recursions, you need only one single check, whereas all others are done only when stop condition is met (i. e. just once).

And you can move calculation of `p` and `t` behind the stop condition(s), you don't use them there anyway...

Comment: For those like me who wondered if `return t+foo(n+1);` would work: Read it as `return operator+(t, foo(n+1));` and it becomes obvious, why it doesn't.

Comment: you know I think the problem is not there because for example for input 200000 the IDE highlightes line `return foo(n-3);`

Comment: @MaryamSadatRazaviTaheri Which problem? You mean that of inputs 0, 1, 2? You might not run into these values when called initially with larger values. But someone might try to test the function with these values initially (at the non-recursive call). So maybe you might check just once in a helper function that calls the recursive variant only if these values are not given. At *very, very* least you'll have to *document* that the function invokes undefined behaviour on these input values.

Comment: @MaryamSadatRazaviTaheri If you don't have negative input, you can simplify your check for `p`: `if(p % 6 != 5) { } else { }`: If `p` is positive, then modulus will be as well, so you don't have to check for < 0. But that's all that's left for the final else, which then can be dropped...

Comment: @MaryamSadatRazaviTaheri Some fine-tuning made that additional function obsolete and even reduced comparisons in recursive calls...